# SQL Command Name is Database Name; Use Dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a database with the name "Union". I am trying execute SQL for this database in the MAINT table but since 'union' is a SQL command it is throwing errors. I can get the query to run when executing from Union database. Would dynamic SQL be able to fix my problem or should I change the database name?

I keep getting incorrect syntax near keyword 'UNION' here is what I have so far,

```
     DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
DECLARE @Database varchar(5)
Set @Database = 'UNION'


SELECT @sql = 'SELECT '+@Database+' as ''Database'', '+@Database+'.hsi.useraccount.username  as ''User Name'', 
'+@Database+'.hsi.useraccount.realname as ''Real Name''
FROM '+@Database+'.hsi.useraccount
WHERE '+@Database+'.hsi.useraccount.username NOT LIKE ''%deactivated%'' and '+@Database+'.hsi.useraccount.username not like ''%administrator'' and '+@Database+'.hsi.useraccount.username not like ''%internal%'''

execute(@sql)
```

Comment: Use square brackets around the name (`[Union]`)

Comment: @Siyual: Might as well make that comment an answer and get proper credit for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `[]` brackets around Schema names.

```
SELECT @sql = REPLACE('SELECT [@Database] as ''Database'', [@Database].hsi.useraccount.username  as ''User Name'', 
[@Database].hsi.useraccount.realname as ''Real Name''
FROM [@Database].hsi.useraccount
WHERE [@Database].hsi.useraccount.username NOT LIKE ''%deactivated%'' and [@Database].hsi.useraccount.username not like ''%administrator'' and [@Database].hsi.useraccount.username not like ''%internal%'''
,'@Database',@Database)
```

As long as the text "@Database" text doesn't appear anywhere else in your select statement, just throw it into a REPLACE() function and avoid all that embedded quote syntax and string concatenation headache.

Answer (score 0):

You also can use quotename instead of manually entering square brackets

```
declare @db nvarchar(100)
set @db='performance'

declare  @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql='select * from '+QUOTENAME(@db)+'.'+quotename('dbo')+'.'+QUOTENAME('orders')
print @sql

exec(@sql)
```